# Current theme unselected. Please check your theme configuration

Tags: prestashop

I have shop on prestashop, and its works fine.
I added another shop on same prestashop instance. When im accessing front of it on browser i have error 500. After checking logs i found error:

`Current theme unselected. Please check your theme configuration.`

Second shop uses the same theme as primary shop. I cant find solution for this.

Comment: https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/628877-current-theme-unselected-please-check-your-theme-configuration-upgrade-from-14-to-15/

Comment: @AndreiLupuleasa, i saw this. But in that topic author was after prestashop update, i am not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found why it didnt work!

in table `*_shop_url` url of new shop has `main` = `0` and it should be `1`!

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest double-checking your `ps_shop` table in the database to make sure the second shop theme is properly configured:

[image: PrestaShop Database ps_shop Table]

Comment: Thx for answer. In 1.6.1.7 there is theme id: https://www.dropbox.com/s/bwgxqbbz8f37kpa/Zrzut%20ekranu%202019-04-25%2010.47.06.png?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

I had that error message and for me the problem was the wrong domain and domain_ssl values in table: *_shop_url

I have moved Presta to another domain and forgot to update *_shop_url